# geometric triangle parallel

Tags: geometric-topology

[image]

$DC$ is parallel to $AB$.

Find the value of $BE$ and $DC$.

I've tried too many times but still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In both cases we can use the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). This says that if you have a triangle with side lengths $a$, $b$, and $c$, with the angle opposite the side of length $c$ as $\theta$, then you have the relation

$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta$$

Notice that in each situation, you have $3$ out of the $4$ variables in this formula, so you can solve for the last one.

Alternatively, if you wanted to, you can use the [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) for the first question. The law of sines states that if you have a triangle with side lengths $a$, $b$, and angles $\theta_a$ and $\theta_b$ such that $\theta_a$ is opposite the side of length $a$ and $\theta_b$ is opposite the side of length $b$, the you have the relation
$$\frac{a}{\sin\theta_a}=\frac{b}{\sin\theta_b}$$

Comment: But my teacher didn't mention about any use of sin or cosine.. I forgot how he did it, but the reason why I didn't write it down is because I wanted to figure it myself and I somehow did.. Question: Is it possible to just take the right triangle which is and rotate it by 90 degrees so that the E is upward, C is downward and D is the point that's to the right. So that would be LABE = LCED?

Comment: @aaaapluss Unfortunately, we can't do that. Even though both triangles have a $30^\circ$ angle, the other angles aren't the same

Comment: Well that's strange because this chapter doesn't even show how to use the cos and sin.